# How to prove that $z_n = 2^n$ converges and therefore has a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have to prove that the following sequence converges and therefore has a limit: $$z_n = 2^n$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have tried to prove it, but I am not seeing exactly what I am doing, that's why I am asking help.

Basically I tried to prove by contradiction (I know it diverges):

Lets assume $z_n$ as a limit $a \in \mathbb{R}$. It follows that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $|a - z_n| < \epsilon$.

I think I have to use now the triangle inequality $|a + b| \leq |a| + |b|$, but I am not seeing exactly how.

Could you please tell me how would I continue/finish this proof?

Comment: If the sequence does not converge (which is the case), then you're never going to be able to prove that it does. Either you have misread the question (maybe it asked you to prove *whether* it converges) or the question is poorly written.

Answer (score 1):

It does **not** converge, unless you meant $z_n = 2^{-n}$. If $z_n = 2^n$, let $M \in \Bbb R_{> 0}$. So exists $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that $n_0 > \log_2 M$, that is, $2^{n_0} > M$. Hence, if $n > n_0$ implies $2^n > 2^{n_0} > M$. Since $M$ was arbitrary, $2^n \to +\infty$.

Comment: You said it converges. "I have to prove that the following sequence converges and therefore has a limit".

Comment: The most important thing at the beginning is to state everything correctly. I think that may have been the principal issue to your confusion. The statement is: "$2^n$ diverges." Your attempted proof was by contradiction. The idea of the contradiction is essentialy the same of what I have done: whatever may be the number, $2^n$ gets higher than that. So you have to prove that given your candidate $a$, you will have $2^n > a$ for infinite values of $n$. Read my answer again thinking of my $M$ as your $a$.

Comment: Actually you don't...

Comment: Recall the definition: $\lim x_n  = +\infty$ if $\forall\, M > 0$ exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n > n_0$ then $x_n > M$. I checked that $2^n$ verifies this property, hence $\lim 2^n = +\infty \not\in \Bbb R$, so $2^n$ has no limit in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $(z_n)$ is convergent. Then $(z_n)$ should be bounded since every convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded, but clearly $2^n$ is unbounded...

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP has been told to prove that $\langle z_i\rangle_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ diverges using only the triangle inequality.

Let me give a couple hints instead of the full answer:

- (1) Suppose $x$ were the limit of the $z_i$s. What must happen to the *distances* between $x$ and $z_n$? (That is, let $d_i=\vert x-2^i\vert$; if $x=\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}z_i$, then what must the sequence $d_i$ behave like?)
- (2) What happens to the distances between the $z_i$s themselves? E.g., what can we say about $\vert 2^a-2^b\vert$? *(In fact, it's enough to think about the distances between successive terms - $2^{a+1}-2^a$ . . .)
- (3) Why is this bad? *(Hint: draw a picture . . .)*

Comment: For bullet point (1), yes! What about the distances between the $z_i$s (bullet point (2))?

Comment: We can say more - what's the distance between $2^1$ and $2^2$? How about $2^3$ and $2^4$? How about $2^{1000}$ and $2^{1001}$?

Comment: Yes - and as $n$ increases what happens to $2^n$?